Why can we define $f(a) = g(a) = 0$ in L'Hopital's rule proof?
Why can we assume $f(a) = g(a) = 0$ in L'Hopital's rule proof?
The theorem itself, does not define the values of functions at $a$. It merely states that the functions approach zero, as $x$ approaches $a$. However, in the proof (at least in Spivak's Calculus), we are using this fact (first underlined statement; ignore the second underlined statement).
What's the justification here, why are we able to do this? I have prompted Claude AI for an answer and it started off interestingly. Stating that we could define functions $F(x) = f(x) - f(a)$ and $G(x) = g(x) - g(a)$ without loss of generality. But its arguments were incorrect when it came to using this trick to show that the limit of ratio equals to the original one (it used the fact that g(a) = 0 to prove it; which is, of course, what we are trying to justify in the first place).


i suppose this is a matter of how you want to define them. this theorem's conditions become its original conditions plus our definition that f(a) = g(a) = 0. But what is curious is that Spivak, explicitly says "changing the previous values of f(a) and g(a), if necessary". Which would suggest that we can define them as such without loss of generality.

Don't use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post.

Spivak's proof shows us the theorem is true in the special case that $f(a) = g(a) = 0$, and we want to deduce the general case where we do not assume $f(a),g(a)$ are necessarily defined at all, or they are defined but not equal to $0$.
The point is that all the assumptions
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = 0,\ \lim_{x\to a}g(x) = 0,\ \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\ \text{exists,}
$$
do not depend on whatever values $f(a),g(a)$ are, or whether they are defined at all. If we are given functions $f(x),g(x)$ which satisfy the assumptions of L'Hopital's rule, but they do not necessarily satisfy $f(a) = g(a) = 0$, then we can just define new functions $F(x),G(x)$ which still satisfy the assumptions and also satisfy the auxiliary condition $F(a) = G(a) = 0$ by making the definitions
$$
F(x) = \begin{cases} f(x), & x \ne a, \\ 0, & x = a, \end{cases},\quad G(x) = \begin{cases} g(x), & x \ne a, \\ 0, & x = a, \end{cases}.
$$
You can and should check that $F(x), G(x)$ still satisfy the assumptions of the theorem. Spivak's proof kicks in now and tells us that the limit $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}$ exists and equals the limit $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{F'(x)}{G'(x)}$. But these last limits are nothing but $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$, respectively (you should check for yourself). This finishes the proof of the general case from the special case.
